# override sails GET blueprint with many-to-one

Tags: node.js, rest, routes, sails.js

caveat: new to web programming.  I have the following in a sails project:

```
// in models/User.js
// user has many videos
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    videos: {
      collection: 'video',
      via: 'owner'
    }
  }
}

// in models/Video.js
// video has one user
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    owner: {
      model: 'user'
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using the REST blueprints with a /v1 prefix.  I'm trying to either override GET /v1/user/:id/video, or make a custom route to GET /v1/user/:id/myGetVideo

So I've tried the following:

1. find and findOne methods in VideoController.js and UserController.js.  These don't trigger for GET /v1/user/:id/video - I guess because the many-to-one association is treated differently
2. creating a custom route

   // in routes.js
   module.exports.routes = {
     'get /user/:id/myGetVideo': 'UserController.myGetVideo'
   }

This doesn't trigger anything because of the namespace, but it does trigger /user/:id/myGetVideo as expected.  I don't want to add /v1 namespace here b/c that will proliferate and become an issue to change versions.

So, how do I either override the method I want, or put it in the namespace?  Overriding the first method seems cleaner, but idk.

Thanks for any help!

Edit: Any comments on what is better practice for a REST API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it with wildcards:

```
// in routes.js 
module.exports.routes = { 'get /v*/user/:id/myGetVideo':'UserController.myGetVideo' }
```

not bullet-proof if the prefix scheme changes, but good enough